# Magento 2 product import problem on windows 7

Tags: magento2

I have tried product import with images on windows 7 using CSV file. It shows error "Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s)". I have set all permission on folders. May I know import products with images on windows 7 is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The product images url/path which you are trying to update are not proper. Can you share some of the image values which you are trying to import, based on that I can suggest.

Comment: thanks for your reply. only images name put on csv file. I can use var/export or pub/media/import folder path.